# Regex to not Match Names

Tags: regex

So my forum allows me to use a regex to allow certain user names registration, but I want to do that opposite and block any non-matches, which the system doesn't allow for inherently.

How can I *not* match a pattern of `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{4}`?

Meaning that it would return false for, say

```
FOobar1234
bar5678
```

I've tried but can't get this to work.

---

Sort of how like `[^a-zA-Z]+` would return false for `foobar` (matches `a-z`) but with 4 digits at the end too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{4}$)
```

In general:

```
^(?!<pattern>$)
```

matches only those strings that do not match the regex `<pattern>`.

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/hiKFgi1Z5P)

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+\d{4})
```

Note that this doesn't actually match the text, it just returns a single zero width match if the string meets your criteria. If you want to match the text as well, use:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+\d{4}$).+$
```